# Calling 2 (two) actions with a submit form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

Want to make this submit button trigger 2 different actions.

1. Search - using the index.php action as shown.
2. Open a new tab or a new window with a landing page (or any page).

The important thing is that the index.php has a "complex" coding for me and going there is going to challenge myself even more. So I prefer to leave the first function as is and somehow add the second "in here".
How can I add the second action?

```
<form class="destinations-form" action="index.php" method="post">
  <div class="input-line">
    <input name="search" type="text" name="destination" value="" 
     class="form-input check-value" placeholder="Looking for..." />
    <button type="submit" name="destination-submit" 
     class="form-submit btn btn-special">GO</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: not posting code in your question is not gonna win you friends here...

Answer (score 0):

you can't put two actions in the form but what you can do is change index.php to index.php?p=landingPage

```
<form class="destinations-form" action="index.php?p=landingPage" method="post">
  <div class="input-line">
    <input name="search" type="text" name="destination" value="" 
     class="form-input check-value" placeholder="Looking for..." />
    <button type="submit" name="destination-submit" 
     class="form-submit btn btn-special">GO</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then in your index.php you can add the following and it will redirect to your landing page.

```
if (isset($_GET['landingPage'])) {
    $redirect="http://mylandingpage.com";
    header("Location: $redirect");
}
```

Comment: Tried, but it's not working. Maybe there's something in the index.php that's messing with your solution.